# Do I have to wait for the didReadRSSI() function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I would like to discover BLE devices in my area and store their current RSSI value. The discovering works but I'm note sure, if my func `didDiscoverPeripheral` is really save... I think that I should wait for the `didReadRSSI` func before I leave the `didDiscoverPeripheral`. But how can I realize that in an easy way and is my opinion right?

```
    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber)
{
    CBperipheral = [peripheral]

    peripheral.readRSSI()
}

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didReadRSSI RSSI: NSNumber, error: NSError?)
{
    //Store the peripheral specific RSSI, Name and identifier
}
```

Comment: You can't "wait" in `didDiscoverPeripheral`.  You need to handle the callback to `didReadRSSI` when it happens.  Also the first line of your `didDiscoverPeripheral` makes no sense.  I would suggest that you create a dictionary of RSSI values keyed by your peripheral.

Comment: Pls see my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like this -

```
var peripherals = Set<CBPeripheral>
var peripheralRSSIs = Dictionary<CBPeripheral,NSNumber>()


func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber)
{
    self.peripherals.insert(peripheral)
    self.peripheralRSSIs[peripheral]=RSSI
    central.connectPeripheral(peripheral,options:nil) // Connect if you want to be able to retrieve additional RSSI values
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
    didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral)
{
    peripheral.delegate=self
    peripheral.readRSSI()
}

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didReadRSSI RSSI: NSNumber, error: NSError?)
{
    if (error != nil) {
        print(error)
    } else {
        self.peripheralRSSIs[peripheral]=RSSI
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this:

```
   func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber)
{
    CBperipheral = [peripheral]
    myStrings.append(StringPair("\(peripheral.name!)", "\(peripheral.name!)", "\(RSSI)"))
    //Coose the right peripheral and connect!
}
```

I don't need very up-to-date values for the RSSI, only some guiding values. So I hope this code is conform with IOS 8 and later.

But it would be nice, if you could tell me the handling with the callback to my `didReadRSSI` for other problems like this.

btw. I have to write this: `CBperipheral = [peripheral]` to call my `didConnectPeripheral` after the call of `CBmanager.connectPeripheral` :)